# Why is coroutine being called after the line below it? Even where there is no delay given to coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In this example,
Why is coroutine being called after the line below it?

Even where there is no delay given to coroutine.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        println("Hello from coroutine")
    }
    println("Hello from outside")
```

Output:

`I/System.out: Hello from outside`

`I/System.out: Hello from courtine`

Comment: Why is that surprising?  Those two lines can run in any order; they're independent, and getting a task to run on what's probably a different thread will take nonzero time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're saying any of the statements can run first? There's a possible that these lines could have been exchanged?

Comment: Yes, of course.  That's how concurrency works.

Comment: I have run this code multiple times, then why do i see the same output everytime? I should have seen atleast one scenario where this situations gets reversed, no? @LouisWasserman

Comment: Not at all.  Just because it's possible doesn't mean it's random or easy to make happen.  That's also part of concurrency, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Dispatchers.Main.immediate](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-coroutine-dispatcher/immediate.html)

> Returns dispatcher that executes coroutines immediately when it is
> already in the right context (e.g. current looper is the same as this
> handler's looper) without an additional re-dispatch.

eg:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
    println("Hello from coroutine")
}
```

> In this example, Why is coroutine being called after the line below
> it?
>
> Even where there is no delay given to coroutine.

If you see how the launch function works, it has a parameter `start` which defaults to [CoroutineStart.DEFAULT](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-start/-d-e-f-a-u-l-t/)

> then the coroutine code is dispatched for execution later, while the
> code that invoked the coroutine builder continues execution.

Comment: That is fine, but i want to understand the scenario of DefaultDispatcher. Please explain the current behvaiour.

Comment: @SagarBalyan Its because of the way coroutines work

Answer (score 0):

Since the `GlobalScope` is used, its `CoroutineContext` defaults to `EmptyCoroutineContext`, which doesn't have any of `CoroutineContext.Element`. So once a coroutine is fired using it, the coroutine will get the `Dispatchers.Default` as a `CoroutineDispatcher` which is backed by a shared pool of threads, meaning that the coroutine code will be executed by a different thread (you can add `${Thread.currentThread().name}` to each `println` to see what thread the code is executed by), hence the order, it's not guaranteed that either one will happen first, it's "random" whichever thread gets there first.

If you were to run this code in a normal Kotlin JVM project through the `main` function, the coroutine code wouldn't be guaranteed to run at all, because the `main` function could've been finished by the time the coroutine gets to be executed (on a separate thread).